# Is there any way to use a variable inside sscanf modifiers

Tags: c, scanf

How can I use a `max_size` variable to get only the desired characters?.

```
int max_size=64;
sscanf(p,"%s %(MAX_SIZE-1)[^\n]",a,b);
```

Comment: You can use `sprintf` to create the `scanf` format string.

Comment: The short answer is, "no".  The `*` you'd like to use for this (by analogy with `printf`) got usurped in `scanf` by the suppress-assignment modifier.

Comment: This is just one of about 17 different serious limitations of `scanf`.  In virtually all circumstances, this function is simply not worth using.  If you care about doing anything sophisticated -- such as, in your case, avoiding buffer overflows -- whatever you want to do is either impossible using `scanf`, or is three times as hard as using some other technique. (And yes, I agree, avoiding buffer overflows isn't "something sophisticated", it's a basic requirement.)

Comment: See [question 12.15](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfvwid.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Thank you all for your fast response, I managed to do it with sprintf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sscanf`, you would have to first prepare the formatting string. Something along:

```
char *fmt;
int r = asprintf(&fmt, "%%s %%%u[^\n]", (unsigned)MAX_SIZE - 1);
if (r < 0) abort();
sscanf(p, fmt, a, b);
free(fmt);
```

The sad part about such solution is that compiler stops warning you about invalid specifiers.